# Поиск слова по нескольким маскам из текста в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame, в котором есть различный текст, из которых нужно вытащить слова по нескольким маскам:

```
Пример найти № 52 прием
Второй пример СС: 32342 алло
Третий пример ГГ 543 вот так
```

Соответственно, есть две маски: `№ xx`, где `хх` - любые две цифры. Во втором случае - `CC: xxxxx`, т.е. любые пять цифр. На выходе нужно получить: `№ 52` и `СС: 32342`. И также необходимо если удалить всю строку, в которой найдется маска `ГГ xxx`.

T.е. на выходе нужно получить:

```
№ 52 
СС: 32342
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [29]: df
Out[29]:
                           text
0       Пример найти № 52 прием
1  Второй пример СС: 32342 алло
2  Третий пример ГГ 543 вот так
```

Решение:

```
mask = df["text"].str.contains(r"ГГ\s\d{3}")
patterns = ["СС:\s+\d{5}", "№\s+\d{2}"]
pat = r"({})".format("|".join(patterns))
res = df.loc[~mask, "text"].str.extract(pat)
```

Результат:

```
           0
0       № 52
1  СС: 32342
```

---

[Regular Expression](https://regex101.com/r/D47kS7/1):

```
In [49]: print(pat)
(СС:\s+\d{5}|№\s+\d{2})
```

Comment: the label [] is not in the [index] выдает

Comment: Это в какой строке?

Comment: в последней строке. Если без `loc`, то `pattern contains no capture groups`

Comment: А что означает `?:` и `\s*` ?

Comment: Указание регулярному выражению не выделять память для совпадения, не сохраняет в группу.

Comment: @Max52, добавил ссылку на разбор RegEx