# Ошибка в регулярном выражении - nothing to repeat at position

Tags: python, pandas

Есть DF:

```
A
primer № 5432/5433`
```

Нужно получить `№ 5432/5433`.

Использую:

```
patterns = ("№\s+\d{4}\/\d{4}")
pat = "({})".format("|".join(patterns))
res = df['A'].str.extract(pat)`
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> nothing to repeat at position 7

, хотя на RegEX все хорошо. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [98]: df
Out[98]:
                    A
0  primer № 5432/5433

In [99]: df["A"].str.extract(r"(№\s*\d{4}/\d{4})")
Out[99]:
             0
0  № 5432/5433
```

или

```
In [107]: patterns = (r"№\s+\d{4}\/\d{4}", )
#  NOTE: ------------------------------) ^

In [108]: pat = "({})".format("|".join(patterns))

In [109]: res = df['A'].str.extract(pat)

In [110]: res
Out[110]:
             0
0  № 5432/5433
```

Answer (score 1):

ваше решение предпологает, что `patterns` - список или кортеж, а вы вместо этого используете скаляр - строку:

```
In [86]: type(patterns)
Out[86]: str
```

решение - чтобы создать кортеж, состоящий из одного элемента - добавьте после элемента запятую:

```
In [87]: patterns = ("№\s+\d{3,5}\/\d{3,5}", )
#  NOTE:   ------------------------>       ^^

In [88]: type(patterns)
Out[88]: tuple
```

---

> может дописать в ответ, как в рег.выр. прописать чтобы цифр было не
>   ровно 4, а от 3 до 5 например, чтобы не писать 3 конструкции?

```
\d{3,5}  # --> регулярное выражение для поиска числа состоящего от 3х до 5ти цифр.
```

Comment: я думал для одного примера тоже прокатит(

Comment: достаточно поставить запятую

Comment: в большой выборке выдает `first argument must be string or compiled pattern`  ((

Comment: Да, все работает, спасибо

Comment: @Max52, [похоже я уже отвечал на этот вопрос...)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1037736/211923)

Comment: Да, просто вот этот момент уточнить хотел. Кстати, может дописать в ответ, как в рег.выр. прописать чтобы цифр было не ровно 4, а от 3 до 5 например, чтобы не писать 3 конструкции

Comment: @Max52, дополнил ответ...